# Console wireless network manager

Tags: networking, kubuntu, 15.04, network-manager

I have installed i3-wm on my Kubuntu 15.04. But I need sometimes to manually choose Wi-Fi networks. I don't like the way I do it now (stating `plasmashell`, choosing Wi-Fi and exiting it), So I'm looking for the program that can:

1. Give me a list of aviable Wi-Fi networks
2. Connect to the network as simple as `connect ESSID PASSWORD`.
   Without any `iwconfig`'s afterward.

Please help me to find such program.

Answer (score 0):

wicd-curses will do what you ask. It will function similar to a GUI based network manager but in the console as the question title implies.